# scala 2.12 + Spark 3 + sedona-sql-3.0_2.12

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geospark, apache-sedona

I'm trying to use sedona with scala and spark. Here is the build.sbt file:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.0.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12" % "3.0.1",
  "org.apache.sedona" % "sedona-python-adapter-2.4_2.11" % "1.2.1-incubating",
  "org.apache.sedona" % "sedona-core-3.0_2.12" % "1.2.1-incubating",
  "org.apache.sedona" % "sedona-sql-3.0_2.12" % "1.2.1-incubating",
  "org.apache.sedona" % "sedona-viz-2.4_2.11" % "1.2.1-incubating"

)
```

The code is working perfectly with scala 2.11 & spark 2.4 but when I switch to spark 3 I get the following error while executing my code:

```
[error] Provider org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.io.GeotiffFileFormat could not be instantiated


 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat$class
[error]         at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.io.GeotiffFileFormat.<init>(GeotiffFileFormat.scala:54)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: According to your sbt dependencies, you are adding both `sedona-viz-2.4_2.11` while the other sedona dependencies are for spark 3+ / scala 2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://sedona.apache.org/setup/maven-coordinates/#use-sedona-fat-jars, the only 3 jars you need are

Please do not add other jars to your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sedona</groupId>
  <artifactId>sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1-incubating</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sedona</groupId>
  <artifactId>sedona-viz-3.0_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1-incubating</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Optional: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datasyslab/geotools-wrapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
    <artifactId>geotools-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-25.2</version>
</dependency>
```